# Status bar not working in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am newbie in IONIC 3, I just want to implement status bar to my app. I tried following methods.

```
import { App, Nav, Platform, Events, AlertController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

constructor(public events: Events, public platform: Platform,   publicstatusBar: StatusBar) {

this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#1972d2');
this.statusBar.isVisible;
```

}

and Changed in index.html page as solution mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/issues/375)

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
```

and also mentioned in config.xml page like this

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#1972d2" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

What might be the issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you did is correct.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- **the plugin `StatusBar` is not installed**. Even if in an empty project in the `app.component.ts` is mentioned, is not installed properly. So you have just to follow this [guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/) on the official documentation.
- **your android device does not support that feature**. For example, there are different custom ROMs that manage the status bar in an unconventional way like MIUI, EMUI, etc. You can check that on this [page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22cordova-plugin-statusbar%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20summary%20ASC%2C%20updatedDate%20DESC) that collects issues of the Cordova plugin.

Anyway, if you do everything listed above it should work but remember to make a build to be sure at 100%

*EDIT*: I've tested it on the MIUI and it works like a charm though, but on the issue page someone got a problem on some device. Maybe it's some particular version.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @resueman. It's working fine now just by updating the statusbar plugin

Comment: @KedarKm I'm glad to hear that, I've done the same error. I don't know why they put in the status bar in the template without the installation of the plugin. By the way, if that helped you can close the question :)