# StatusBar not showing on MIUI and EMUI devices

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, statusbar, miui

I created app for Android(with Xamarin Classic). I did the testing and everything is fine, except for one thing: StatusBar not showing on [MIUI](http://en.miui.com/) and [EMUI](https://emui.huawei.com/). 
I understand that these firmware have their own peculiarities. but I almost did not find any information about it. Only this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704555/status-bar-not-working-in-ionic-3/51114158#51114158), this quote:

> your android device does not support that feature. For example, there
>   are different custom ROMs that manage the status bar in an
>   unconventional way like MIUI, EMUI, etc.

Please help me,  any tips and tricks.

Comment: Have you turned on Demo mode in developer options?